# IE6 can not start up jvm when there's the "applet" tag in the page

Tags: java, applet

My english is bad ,I hope you can understand what i said.

there's a page which contain a applet tag.when it is loaded by IE6,the IE6 can not start up the jvm.
in other computer ,it's ok.but it can't be start up on my computer.

Comment: Is the JRE installed properly? Does the applet load in other browsers?

Comment: I wouldn't mind discovering the reasons why an old tool like IE6 does not work, it's a waste of time. Just dismiss it.

Comment: I just setup the java jdk 1.6.but it can be startup in other computer.

Comment: for gd1: in my company,there are many computer to user ie6.so i must find the reason.

Comment: to Gabriel Negut : I cann't install other browser to test .so i don't know if it can be load in other browser.but it can be load in other computer whit IE6 and jdk 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a config problem. Java may not be enabled in the IE6 on your computer.

Comment: how can i make sure where is the problem.

Comment: Check in Internet Options > Advanced look for JVM and make sure it is checked. If JVM is not present then, you need to install it and restart the browser.